# where is struct field that created by new (heap or stack)?

Tags: c++, heap-memory, stack-memory

i read about stack and heap
but i don't know about this

where is x ( in heap or in stack ) ?
is my code have a memory leak or not ?

```
struct st
{
    int x;
    int* y;
};

st* stp;

void func()
{
    st* s=new st();

    s->x=2;
    s->y=new int(5);

    stp=s;
}

int _tmain(int argc, TCHAR* argv[], TCHAR* envp[])
{

    func();

    cout << stp->x << "  " << *stp->y <<endl;

    delete stp->y;
    delete stp;
}
```

output 
2   5

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`stp` is dynamically-allocated, and is therefore on the heap.<sup>*</sup>  Therefore, all its members (including `x`) are on the heap.

As far as I can see, you don't have a memory leak.

---

<sub>* Technically, the C++ standard doesn't talk about stack vs. heap, so it's up to the compiler where stuff gets allocated.  But in practice, it will be stored in a heap-like structure.</sub>

Comment: There are memory leaks if either the second `new` or the console output (or any other code that might be added in the future before deleting) throws.

Answer (score 0):

Dynamically allocated variables (like your stp) are generally stored in the heap (unless you are calling a special allocation function that works on the stack like alloca).
I do not see a memory leakage.

Answer (score 0):

when you use `new` or `malloc()` the memory is normally allocated from the `heap`. When you allocate an object within a function, it goes on the `stack`.

so, since you use `new st()`, the x within the struct is allocated on the heap.
and no, no memory leak spotted here!